# How to refresh the binding again using mvvmlight

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

[image]

The `CurrentSelectedBall` is updated whenever I changed its value due to two-way binding.
When I click to update the function `UpdateRedBall` is called so the redball in the database is updated. But the view list of balls is not updated as the `ObservableCollection<RedBall> RedBalls` is not changed at all.

How to fix this problem? I guess something needs to be done after `_context.SaveChanges();`
Also I can not simply do `DataGridA.itemsSource = RedBalls` to make a hard refresh here as first `DataGridA` is not accessible in the MainviewModel.

Some of the methods:

```
public ObservableCollection<RedBall> RedBalls
{
    get { return new ObservableCollection<RedBall>(_context.RedBalls.OrderBy(m=>m.DateNumber));}
    set
    {
        _redBalls = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("RedBalls");
    }
}
public RedBall CurrentSelectedRedBall
{
    get { return _currentSelectedRedBall; }
    set
    {
        _currentSelectedRedBall = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentSelectedRedBall");
    }
}
private void UpdateRedBall()
{
    if (CurrentSelectedRedBall != null)
    {
        var ballToUpdate = _context.RedBalls.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == CurrentSelectedRedBall.Id);
        ballToUpdate.DateNumber = CurrentSelectedRedBall.DateNumber;
        ballToUpdate.First = CurrentSelectedRedBall.First;
        ballToUpdate.Second = CurrentSelectedRedBall.Second;
        ballToUpdate.Third = CurrentSelectedRedBall.Third;
        ballToUpdate.Fourth = CurrentSelectedRedBall.Fourth;
        ballToUpdate.Fifth = CurrentSelectedRedBall.Fifth;
        ballToUpdate.Sixth = CurrentSelectedRedBall.Sixth;
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    //RedBalls = RedBalls

}
```

Comment: Does your `RedBall` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? If not, then the UI will not be notified about the changes you made to the selected `RedBall` and your grid will continue to display old data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a strong dislike for getters that 'do stuff'. It should be impossible for a get to fail. I would consider moving the logic in your RedBalls getter elsewhere. I'm also concerned that you're newing up the RedBalls ObservableCollection on every get as it can cause problems with bindings. Bound ObservableCollections should be instantiated once, then altered using Add, Remove and Clear. Working with them this way should also solve the problem of updating your collection appropriately.

```
public ObservableCollection<RedBall> RedBalls
{
    get { return _redBalls; }
    set
    {
        _redBalls = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("RedBalls");
    }
}

public RedBall CurrentSelectedRedBall
{
    get { return _currentSelectedRedBall; }
    set
    {
        _currentSelectedRedBall = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentSelectedRedBall");
    }
}

private void UpdateCurrentSelectedRedBall()
{
    UpdateRedBall();

    var redBalls = _context.RedBalls.OrderBy(m=>m.DateNumber);
    if(redBalls != null)
    {
        RedBalls.Clear();
        foreach(RedBall rb in redBalls)
        {
            RedBalls.Add(rb);
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateRedBall()
{
    if (CurrentSelectedRedBall != null)
    {
        var ballToUpdate = _context.RedBalls.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == CurrentSelectedRedBall.Id);
        ballToUpdate.DateNumber = CurrentSelectedRedBall.DateNumber;
        ballToUpdate.First = CurrentSelectedRedBall.First;
        ballToUpdate.Second = CurrentSelectedRedBall.Second;
        ballToUpdate.Third = CurrentSelectedRedBall.Third;
        ballToUpdate.Fourth = CurrentSelectedRedBall.Fourth;
        ballToUpdate.Fifth = CurrentSelectedRedBall.Fifth;
        ballToUpdate.Sixth = CurrentSelectedRedBall.Sixth;
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this: https://gist.github.com/itajaja/7507120 - basically you need to subscribe for PropertyChanged and raise CollectionChanged events from that.